# Get a string from a large html variable

Tags: php, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

How would I go about getting a certain string from a webpage that has been scraped?
I am using SimpleBrowser in PHP to download a webpage into a variable.

The resultant webpage at a certain part has the following:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="label" width="350">POD Receiver Name:&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="field" align="left">
            <b>KRISTY</b>&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I want to get the value KRISTY into a variable, but not really sure how.
I have no real experience with regex so I wouldnt know where to start.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Regex would definitely not be the way to go here...

Comment: Thanks for that. Going to have a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull one specific part out from a known location, I'd use xpath.  Try a tutorial such as http://ditio.net/2008/12/01/php-xpath-tutorial-advanced-xml-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are storing a page in a variable. But if you have a page stored as a string in a variable you can use Regular expression to extract string out of it. For this particular example you can use something like this.

```
$v = '<tr>
       <td class="label" width="350">POD Receiver Name:&nbsp;</td>
       <td class="field" align="left">
        <b>KRISTY</b>&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>';

preg_match('/\<b\>(.*?)\<\/b\>/', $v, $matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

This particular regular expression gets everything between the bold tags.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure can be depended on, give SimpleXML a shot:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(html_entity_decode($v));
$name = strval($xml->td[1]->b);//KRISTY
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php